# Create backup of Postgres DB schemas

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore

I have two servers and 5 schemes in Postgres, one server is in production and the other is in the background.

- Windows server 2019
- Postgres 12.7

I have these schemas in the postgres database which is by default, I guess it is not the best option. But this is the scenario.

On the production server I have much more data since it is the one that is operating, what I want to do is copy the database on the production server and copy it to the secondary one since I need to do some tests, but safely.

Tried this with no positive result:

```
pg_dump.exe -U postgres -d postgres --format=c -f db.sql
```

And on secondary server the following:

```
pg_restore.exe --create --clean --if-exists -Fc -d postgres -U postgres "db.sql"
```

I thought I could do it only with the diagrams in the following way:

```
pg_dump.exe --file "db.sql" --username "postgres" --format=c --blobs --schema-only --schema "schema" "postgres"

pg_restore.exe --username "postgres" --dbname "postgres" --schema-only --verbose --schema "schema" "db.sql"
```

But I think it would not be a valid option either, would I have to do a clean when restoring? just copy the data with the --only-data option? How could I completely copy the schema at the source, and rewrite it completely at the destination? with the clean option?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `--clean` and `--create`, `pg_restore` will run

```
DROP DATABASE postgres;
CREATE DATABASE postgres;
```

Then it will try to connect to that database and restore the data. But the `DROP DATABASE` will fail, because `pg_restore` is connected to the database you are trying to drop.

If you want to drop and re-create the `postgres` database, you have to connect to a different database with `pg_restore`. One possibility is to use `template1`:

```bash
pg_restore --create --clean -d template1 -U postgres db.sql
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll write it down for next time, in the end I decided to copy the SCHEMA alone

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution to the problem.

In the end I opted to backup the schemas only, not the database,there were 5 of them, not too many. Use the commands I put above, you only had to drop the schemas in the receiving database as follows:

```
DROP SCHEMA "name" CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA "name";
```

After this I only had to do the restore as I mentioned above.

Thanks.